# Java- XMLSignature validation fails in weblogic

Tags: java, xml, validation, weblogic, signature

I am working on a web service, developed in Java, that receives an object as parameter. One of it's properties is a XML signed with `XMLSignature`. Based on a few examples I found online I created some methods for signing and validating an XML.

I have tested my code locally (i.e. using a simple console app) and it worked fine. However when i deployed it to weblogic (local server) it failed the validation. I'm stuck and I can't figure out why it fails.

Here is the `XMLSignature` code: https://gist.github.com/4118253

Also, I am using `JDev` 11.1.1.1 (Java v1.6.0_11) and `WebLogic` Server 10.3.1.0. I'll gladly provide any other relevant information that will help understand why it doesn't work.

Thanks.